# Gimp: print gets reduced by a few mm in both dimensions

Tags: gimp

I am using `GIMP 2.10.8` for making 36mm x 46mm photos. To achieve this size i am doing following:

1. Fixing aspect ratio to `360:460`
2. Cropping the selection and scaling it using following settings:

[image]

3. Arranging these images on an `A4` template by `Edit`->`Copy` and `Paste into Selection`.
4. Measured dimensions of the photo as appeared on GIMP `A4` template remain same as what it was scaled to (Approximately 36mm x 46mm).
5. Printing it on A4 paper i get the images reduced by 3 mm in both dimensions i.e. 33mm x 43mm. Print settings are as following:

[image]

Why the printed size is less? If i print only one photo without pasting it on `A4` template i get correct size. I see same issue when using `Filter` ->`Tile` option as well.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think it's possible to answer this without access to your printer. If I were to attempt a guess it would be that many printers can't print all the way to the edge of a sheet, and when you print and have the settings set up to "fit to page" in your print dialog, it will reduce the size to fit only the printable part of a sheet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Billy!, Though "fit to page" is unchecked in my settings but as mentioned in comment to Rafel's answer, printer does not seem to detecting the 10PPmm resolution and setting it to 10.74PPmm. Considering my problem is due to a potential printer or its settings issue,  for now i proceeded with one photo at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not due to Gimp, but because of the relationship between inches and cm.

When you define the PPI each pixel has now an exact physical dimension but defined as a fraction of an inch. In this case 1/300 of an inch. In cm, this would be 1/118.1102362204724 As you can see this has a big set of decimals of imprecision.

If you want exact pixels, use pixels per cm, not pixels per inch. You can round it to just 118 PPcm or 12 PPmm.

As in reality beyond 200PPI are really difficult to spot, you can use a nicer round number of 100PPcm or 10PPmm. This would be exactly 254PPI.

---

One additional thing about your specific printer, it can just be that your printer is fitting the image to the maximum area it can actually print.

Not every printer can print A4 on an A4 paper. Normally they need a small margin so the ink does not get spilled all around your printer, and some extra margin to push the paper at the end.

Comment: Tried setting 10PPmm for the A4 template as well as for the photo being pasted in multiples on the template.  But when i hit print i see printer is set to print it with 10.74PPmm and results in print with approx 3mm lesser width each photo. Thanks for helpful details, i will look in to printer's settings further.